# Can I put a bounty on a question using reputation from stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

The title sums up my question. I am having an issue that I cannot FOR THE LIFE OF ME figure out, I have even gone through system logs to try and figure out the issue and have googled everything that even closely relates to my issue and tried it with no solution that works. I would like to put a bounty on it, but I don't have enough reputation on this, nor do I have the linux skills to gain reputation. Is there any way I could use my stack overflow reputation?

Comment: Why not just post the question and see if you get a useful answer?   You can't set a bounty immediately, anyway. And who knows, the question itself might be popular enough that it gets you another 60 rep points. Anything is possible if you believe in yourself (insert more inane "inspirational" dreck here) :-)

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: no.

In *theory* you could *start* with a profile on another site, accumulate 200 reputation points, *then* create a Unix & Linux profile, which would be awarded a 100-point association bonus, which would be above the 75-point privilege level for awarding bounties. Setting a 50-point bounty would immediately set you back below the privilege level, but it would accomplish the goal of assigning a bounty. See [What is the association bonus, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work) for more about the association bonus.

Unfortunately, your U&L profile appears to be older than your SO profile, so you cannot use that method. You'll need to get above the 75-point privilege level with your U&L profile before you can set a bounty.

There are a couple pages here on Meta that I'd point you to:

- [What's the best way to get more points?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/528/whats-the-best-way-to-get-more-points)
- [How to get reputation here on Unix & Linux stack exchange?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3484/how-to-get-reputation-here-on-unix-linux-stack-exchange)

Comment: I don't think that part about the order of creation is right. The association bonus is granted once you get 200 on any site, not just the first one.

Comment: Why only "in theory"? The bounty I placed on [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114106/121607) came right out of my association bonus - that was really handy as I needed an answer fast and joined Pi SE mostly to ask that question ;)

Comment: @muru true; I'll edit the answer in a bit to clarify.

Comment: @AdminBee because it's possible, but not in James E's situation.

Answer (score -4):

You must have a minimum of 75 reputation on this site to set a bounty. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties details this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is whether you can use reputation points from another site to create your bounty.